# If I want to prove a sequence converges to a limit, but I chose the wrong limit, what contradiction should I expect to get?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have the sequence that is defined by the formula $u_n=\frac{3n-1}{n+1}$ and I suspect that the limit of this sequence as $n$ approaches infinity is $3$. I can prove it using the definition of a convergent series, which states that $L$ is the limit if the sequence if for any $\epsilon\leq 0$, there is a minimum value of $m$, such that when $n\geq m$, $\left|u_n-L \right|\leq \epsilon$.

$$\left|\frac{3n-1}{n+1}-3 \right|=\left| \frac{3n-1-3n-4}{n+1}\right|=\frac{4}{n+1}$$

If $\left|u_n-L \right|\leq \epsilon$, then $\frac{4}{n+1}\leq \epsilon$, which means that:

$$\frac{4}{n+1}\leq \epsilon$$

$$\frac{4}{\epsilon}-1\leq n$$

This shows that there are always going to be some values for $n$, for any $\epsilon$.

My question is what if my initial suspicion was incorrect, what sort of contradictory result should I have been expecting in this example or in general. If I have a sequence with a general term $u_n$ and which I know is convergent, and I want to use the definition to prove it is convergent, but I happen to chose the incorrect L?

Comment: A useful general trick is to divide numerator and denominator by the highest occuring power of $n$. Almost all terms will tend to $0$ then. Unless you have to use $\epsilon-\delta$ calculation.

Comment: For the "contradictory result", consider the negation of "sequence converging to limit":

$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb N: \exists n \ge N: |u_n - L| \ge \epsilon$$

That is, for any bounding $N$, we can find some term after $u_N$ that is outside the desired range.

Comment: Take $L=2$ for example instead of $L=3$; then for $\epsilon<1$ you'll get $n\leq (\epsilon+3)/(1-\epsilon)$ a contradiction.

Comment: Why do you talk about series in the title of the question, whereas the body is about sequences.

Comment: A totally non-math answer to your question: suppose that you have a **bullet** that you assume will get closer and closer to a target (or perhaps hit the target).  If your assumption is correct that the bullet will approach some target, but your guess is wrong about the location of the target, and if the distance between the 2 targets is (for example) D, it is easy to see that there must be some point beyond which the bullet stays very close to the 1st target.  Therefore, beyond this point, the bullet never even approaches being within D/2 of the 2nd (wrongly suspected) target.

Comment: For a slightly different scenario, where you know that a function is bounded, and you think that because of this that the function must converge to a target, imagine the sequence $a_n = \sin ~n$ against the backdrop of the sine curve.  Make the simplifying assumption that this sequence never converges.  Then the combination of its being both divergent + bounded is due to the **oscillating** nature of the sine curve.  You can similarly consider the sequence $\{+1, -1, +1, -1, +\cdots, -\cdots\}$.